# Determining BCNF violations

Tags: database, functional-dependencies, bcnf

So I have a relation schema with FD's that look like this:

```
R(A,B,C,D): AB -> C, B -> D, CD -> A, AD -> B
```

Now I'm trying to find all the BCNF violations and then decompose the tables. I computed the left hand side of all the FD's and found this:

```
AB+ = {A, B, C, D}
B+ = {B, D} <- violation
CD+ = {C, D, A, B}
AD+ = {A, D, B, C}
```

So I decompose the table to look like this:

```
R1 (B, D)
R2 (A, B, C)
```

The only problem is that I'm not sure if this is all I have to do when it comes to decomposing the tables or if I have to do more. I'm mainly confused about the AB, CD, and AD parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `B → D` is in effect the only dependency that violates the BCNF, since in all the other depedencies the left hand side is a key (actually all the keys of the relation are  `(A D)`, `(A B)`, `(B C)` and  `(C D)`).

So, you can decompose by splitting the original relation `R` in `R1,` containing `B+`, that is `BD`, and `R2`, containing `R - B+ + B`, that is `ABC`, as you have correctly found.

Then one should apply again this process if in any of the decomposed relation there is some dependency that violates the BCNF. But this is not the case, since the only dependency in `R1` is `B → D`, with B the only key, and with the dependencies `AB → C` and `BC → A` in `R2`, that has keys `AB` and `BC`.

At this point can terminate the process since `R1` and `R2` are both in BCNF. But we should note also that this decomposition *does not* preserve the dependencies, since `CD → A` and `AD → B` have been lost.

Comment: The only thing I was wondering about was CD and AD so I assume that there's nothing I can do to preserve those dependencies.

Comment: Yes, it is well known that the algorithm to decompose a relation in BCNF can cause a loss of dependencies. Consider for instance AD-> B. To preserve this dependency you could add a new relation ADB, but then it will have the dependency B-> D that violates the normal form. So you should decompose in BD and AB, and again you will lose the dependency.